# SharePoint Migration from on-prem to online Date time minus 1-hour issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

I'm working on migrating SharePoint 2016 hosted apps to SharePoint online with all contents in all lists.
The issue that I have faced that always I get date time minus 1 hour on all columns type date-time.

For example, I have a list that contains 2 columns plus created and modified:

| Column Name | Column Type | SharePoint on-prem 2016 | SharePoint online |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Title | Text | Reservation | Reservation |
| Need At | Date Time | 8/13/2018 11:00 PM | 8/13/2018 10:00 PM |
| Created | Date Time | 8/15/2018 10:47 AM | 8/15/2018 09:47 AM |
| Modified | Date Time | 9/21/2018 04:55 AM | 9/21/2018 03:55 AM |

Those are the solution that I have tried:

- Regional time be the same.
- Change the regional time in SharePoint to +1.
- Migrating to SharePoint on-prem 2019.
- Change site collection.

But always the same issue...

Please note that I'm using SharePoint online migration tool powered by Microsoft and Also I tried my own PowerShell script when I have tested with SharePoint on-prem 2019.

Could you please help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see this behavior in my environment. The Regional settings are set differently from my test so it should not be the issue. I have the system time set as the same on all my machines though.

Check your local system time settings. Clear the browser cache if necessary.

Also make sure you use the latest version of the tool: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/new-and-improved-features-in-the-sharepoint-migration-tool.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, i tested the latest version but always the same issue.
I changed the regional setiings as per request of Microsoft team.

Comment: @Style5000 Do you mean you have a support ticket open with Microsoft?

Comment: Yes, but they still diagnostic the issue...

Comment: @Style5000 It doesn't look like a server side issue to me. Have you considered testing on another end machine (from your colleague, for example) to see if it makes a difference?